# Class binding error after binding model

Tags: angular

I have the following form input:

```
<div [ngClass]="{selected: roleName.valid}">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.RoleName" ngControl="roleName" #roleName="ngForm" id="roleName" />
</div>
```

I bind the model in OnInit event. The problem is I'm getting the following error:

```
Expression '{selected: roleName.valid} in RoleEditComponent@8:21' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null'. Current value: 'false' in [{selected: roleName.valid}
```

I know I can disable this error enabling prod mode but I'm not sure if it's a good idea. What's wrong with my approach and how can I fix this?

**Edit**

I just realized this happens without even setting the model. Sample code : http://plnkr.co/edit/dFlxNAfC0VRy9BtRampW?p=preview

Comment: That's right, switching to prodMode is not a silution. I guess the problem is where you initialize `roleName.valid`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I just use the default FormBuilder in ctor: this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            roleName: ['', Validators.required],
            roleDescription: ['']
        });

Comment: and where are you usimg it?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean by that. The form is model-driven with simple FormBuilder in ctor and I set the model in OnInit. Can you eloberate please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

I think this is a known issue when the properties of a control are accessed this way (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8139).

If you get the control reference from the form, the error doesn't occur.

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form" form="ngForm">
    <div [ngClass]="{'has-error': form.controls.roleName.valid}">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.RoleName" ngControl="roleName" #roleName="ngForm" id="roleName" />
    </div>
</form>`,
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PrtNtKzwalDzRz7WtB5v?p=info)

See also [Angular2 and disabling button exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590376/angular2-and-disabling-button-exception)

**original**

`ngOnInit()` is a lifecycle callback called by Angulars change detection. Angulars change detection doesn't like when it's actions cause model changes. This is usually the cause for "Expression x has changed after .."

You can either wrap your code in `ngOnInit()` into `setTimeout(() => ...)` delay it's execution after change detection lifecycle callbacks are done or move it somewhere else (constructor for example).

Comment: What is the best practice to load page model on load? Which event should I use? I remember reading somewhere not to do it constructor but I'm not sure.

Comment: Constructors shouldn't do expensive work and only initialize local fields. DOM access in the constructor would be bad practice but that's quite limited in Angular anyway (before `ngAfterViewInit()`). If you fetch data from a server then I think it's fine to initiate this in the constructor because the actual work is done later anyway because async execution is queued in the event queue for later execution. Besides that it's difficult to say without more information about dependencies,  requirements, and constraints the initialization has to fulfill in your actual use case.

Comment: I've moved my fetch call to constructor but still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the code to your question. It's hard to discuss possible bugs in code that is just explained in prose without any detail.

Comment: I just realized this happens without even setting the model. I added sample code to my post.

Comment: I don't get any error in the Plunker. How can I reproduce? Is there something missing in the Plunker?

Comment: It's true your updated answer works but it continues to happen when you update the model: http://plnkr.co/edit/5Ur94o?p=preview . Anyway since it's a known bug I'll try newer builds. Thank you.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine after updating to beta.16 http://plnkr.co/edit/AFhYnp?p=preview (also with direct field reference)